# REgular expression - allow dashes?

Tags: regex

I have the following javascript that does not allow the user to input any special characters into a field, but I do want to make an exception and allow for a dash (-):

```
function Validate(txt)
{
    txt.value = txt.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9\n\r]+/g, '');
}
```

How to modify it to add the dash to the allowed list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To allow the dash (`-`), all you need to do is to change this: `txt.value = txt.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9\n\r]+/g, '');` to this: `txt.value = txt.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9\n\r-]+/g, '');`.

Note that the dash is a special character when enclosed within the square brackets (it denotes a range) so it **must** be places last within the square brackets.

As per *@Tim Pietzcker*'s comment, you can also escape it `txt.value = txt.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9\n\r\-]+/g, '');` or put it at the front: `txt.value = txt.value.replace(/[^-a-zA-Z 0-9\n\r]+/g, '');`.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: Thanks for the tip, updated answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Add a dash in the end of your character class (as a last character):

```
txt.value = txt.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9\n\r-]+/g, '');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: 
[^a-zA-Z 0-9\n\r-]+

[Cool Site for Regex-testing](http://regexpal.com/)

Answer (score 1):

```
txt.value = txt.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9\n\r-]+/g, '');
```

if the dash is not at the final you can also try this

```
[^a-zA-Z 0-9\n\-\r]+ //I only test this on rubular
```

[TEST](http://www.rubular.com/r/j6ybadbjFE)